# Run a query within MS Access

Tags: python, winapi, ms-access, odbc

I am not very familiar with python yet. I have added `win32`, imported `odbc` in my code, opened a connection to a database.

I would like to run a query stored in the database.

When I add the update query to the code and try to run it, I get the following message:

> opError: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The query cannot be
>   completed. Either the size of the query result is larger than the
>   maximum size of a database (2 GB), or there is not enough temporary
>   storage space on the disk to store the query result. in EXEC

The amount of data I am manipulating is quite large and the specific query I am trying to run is not efficient.

Is there something similar like in visual basic `doCmd`?

Thanks.